# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 arguments, 1 given

Tags: mysqli, php7

muy buenas tardes espero me puedan ayudar. estoy actualizando un login a php 7.
de sql a sqli pero me aparece el siguente error en la linea 21 que seria esta:

```
$log = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sessiones_matriculas WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 arguments, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_antiguo\validar.php:21 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login_antiguo\validar.php(21): mysqli_query('SELECT * FROM s...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login_antiguo\validar.php on line 21

les dejo mi codigo para ver si me pueden ayudar a corregir por favor

archivo  login .php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include 'serv.php';
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
        }
?>

            <h1 class="h1" style="color:white">Login</h1>
            <form method="post" action="validar.php">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" autocomplete="off" style="width:500px"  placeholder=" Nombre de Usuario" required><br>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pw" autocomplete="off" style="width:500px"  placeholder=" Contraseña"  required><br><br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="login" value="Iniciar Sesión">
            </form>
            <button type="button" onClick="window.location='../index.php';">
                            Pagina Principal
            </button>
```

archivo  validar .php

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<head>
    <title>Validando...</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
</head>
<body>


    
        <?php
            include 'serv.php';
            if(isset($_POST['login'])){
                $usuario = $_POST['user'];
                $pw = $_POST['pw'];
                $log = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM sessiones_matriculas WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
                if (mysqli_num_rows($log)>0) {
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($log);
                    $_SESSION["full_name"] = $row['full_name']; 
                    echo 'Iniciando sesión para '.$_SESSION['full_name'].' <p>';
                    echo '<script> window.location="panel.php"; </script>';
                }
                else{
                    echo '<script> alert("Usuario o contraseña incorrectos.");</script>';
                    echo '<script> window.location="index.php"; </script>';
                }
            }
        ?>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que en serv.php tienes las isntrucciones para conectar con la base de datos. En ella creas un *conector* con la base, ese *conector* es el argumento que te falta:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "base");
$log = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM sessiones_matriculas WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
```

Si usas objetos ( a mi me gustan más) tendrías algo así

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "base");
$log = $link->query("SELECT * FROM sessiones_matriculas WHERE user='$usuario' AND pw='$pw'");
```

Pero también implica más cambios al código en tu caso.

Comment: Gracias, es la respuesta correcta. Saludos.